# Unlink doesn't delete the file

Tags: php

I am doing a page where the user can delete the file he uploaded. And i am trying to delete it , but it doesn't seem to work.

First I am creating the directory that will contain the files. 
And i am creating it like this :
 `mkdir($filepath , 0777 , true);`

The part with creating the file works just perfect. Back to the delete page , I am trying to do it like this : 
`unlink("PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $settings->name");`

And the `PROOT` is the root of the file , as i am doing object oriented programming and i am doing it from security reasons , and also the `DS` is the separator.

A `vardump` of the parameter from link would look like this `/framework/files/4/peep(2).jpg` and the link of the file looks like this `http://localhost/framework/files/4/peep(2).jpg` and i am 100% sure that there is not a a problem with the `PROOT` or the `DS`.

Comment: `unlink("PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $settings->name");` is not syntactically correct. You should get unclosed quote errors or your variable expansion is not working correctly because of your two outer double quotes

Comment: `unlink("PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir . DS . $settings->name");` should be: `unlink(PROOT . "files" . DS . $dir . DS . $settings->name);`

Comment: @bassxzero - looks like they can just remove the `"` if those are constants.  `unlink(PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $settings->name);`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if the echo of the file counts as open , then yes , but i am doing this in a method that will redirect me after it gets deleted . As i have a delete button that will call the method with the id.

Comment: @Anuga no , it doesn't work

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix then no

Comment: @bassxzero  no , it doesn't work

Comment: @AxwellVail - remove the double quotes `"` from unlink.  Your file is this `PROOT.files.DS.$dir.DS.` the rest is probably a syntax error.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the line of code look like that now `unlink(PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $settings->name); ` but it doesn't work either

Comment: Yes, because `"PROOT"` is literally `PROOT` as a string.  Not the value of it as a constant.  And the same for the rest of the constants.  Then `"$settings->name"` is a syntax error `"{$settings->name}"`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ac9d8978f4abaa3e9dfaa15eac2afd3df21d190)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix have you seen my last comment ? It doesn't work , even like this `unlink(PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir . DS . $settings->name);`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix then how should it look ?

Comment: Well what does `It doesn't work` mean.  Do you have any errors, have you echoed the value of that out and compared it to the filename etc.  It certainly won't work the way you had it, it would have been a syntax error, which nothing was said about.  So forgive me if I don't understand, but you have to give us more information.  besides `it doesnt works`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix nothing happens , no error.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the `vardump` of the unlink parameter looks like  `/framework/files/4/peep(2).jpg` and the file path is `http://localhost/framework/files/4/peep(2).jpg`

Comment: You need to put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` at the beginning of the path to get the filesystem path that corresponds to the URL.

Comment: @Barmar Appreciated man, add as a reply if you want . It fixed my code after hours!

Comment: Turn on error reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, you have quotes around the concatenation, which is making everything literal except for `$dir` and `$settings->name`.

Second, the variable you should use for the root is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, not `PROOT`.

So it should be:

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'files' . DS . $dir  . DS . $settings->name);
```